# Why Utf8 is compatible with ascii

Tags: string, utf-8, ascii

`A` in UTF-8 is `U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A`. `A` in ASCII is `065`.

How is UTF-8 is backwards-compatible with ASCII?

Comment: Any text file encoded in ASCII can be decoded as UTF-8 to get exactly the same result.

Comment: you are comparing decimal and hex. 65 dec = 41 hex. utf-8 is almost always listed in hex.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

ASCII uses only the first 7 bits of an 8 bit byte. So all combinations from `00000000` to `01111111`. All 128 bytes in this range are mapped to a specific character.

UTF-8 keeps these exact mappings. The character represented by `01101011` in ASCII is also represented by the same byte in UTF-8. All other characters are encoded in sequences of multiple bytes in which each byte has the highest bit set; i.e. every byte of all non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 is of the form `1xxxxxxx`.

Comment: Can you explain what happen if the application that support only ASCII  file read UTF8 file. Specifically, what it suppose to do when it read  the first byte of 0041 (hexadecimal).

Comment: What exactly does "0041" mean? The Unicode character U+0041? The byte sequence `0x00 0x41`? If the former, that's the letter "A", which encoded in UTF-8 **is the same as in ASCII**, so no problems there at all. If the latter, that would be a `NUL` byte followed by "A", which is the same in ASCII as it is in UTF-8. I think you haven't quite gotten the point yet, I'd suggest you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 8):

Unicode is backward compatible with ASCII because ASCII is a subset of Unicode. Unicode simply uses all character codes in ASCII and adds more.

Although character codes are generally written out as 0041 in Unicode, the character codes are numeric so 0041 is the same value as (hexadecimal) 41.

UTF-8 is not a character set but an encoding used with Unicode. It happens to be compatible with ASCII too, because the codes used for multiple byte encodings lie in the part of the ASCII character set that is unused.

Note that it's only the 7-bit ASCII character set that is compatible with Unicode and UTF-8, the 8-bit character sets based on ASCII, like IBM850 and windows-1250, uses the part of the character set where UTF-8 has codes for multiple byte encodings.

Comment: "Note that it's only the 7-bit ASCII character set that is compatible with Unicode and UTF-8": you should remove the mention to Unicode, or you have to define what "compatible" means in this context

Answer (score 6):

Why:

Because everything was already in ASCII and have a backwards compatible Unicode format made adoption much easier. It's much easier to convert a program to use UTF-8 than it is to UTF-16, and that program inherits the backwards compatible nature by still working with ASCII.

How:

ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, but is always stored in bytes, which are 8 bit. That means 1 bit has always been unused.

UTF-8 simply uses that extra bit to signify non-ASCII characters.