# Can VideoJs display subtitles in chinese?

Tags: utf-8, video.js

I just started using VideoJS. Quite impressed with the ease of initial setup of the Javascript library and the clean integration of videos into web pages.

However I encountered an issue of displaying subtitles in a foreign language (e.g. Chinese). The following is the code for embedding video

```
 <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  preload="none" width="640"
           height="264" poster="Image/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="Video/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>             
    <track kind="captions" src="video-js/demo.captions_C.vtt" srclang="zh" label="Chinese" default></track>
    <track kind="captions" src="video-js/demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
    <!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->            
    <track kind="subtitles" src="video-js/demo.captions_C.vtt" srclang="zh" label="Chinese" default></track>
    <track kind="subtitles" src="video-js/demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
    <!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that 
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
```

The issues I have are:

1) The Chinese captions in "demo.captions_C.vtt" are not displayed, even if it is set as default. Instead, captions in "demo.captions.vtt is " are displayed.

2) I tried to select "Chinese" in the caption menu. There was no response and no change.

The "demo.captions_C.vtt" is provided below:

```html
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:02.332
这是中文字幕

00:02.332 --> 00:10.947
海鸥的英雄礼赞音乐

00:10.947 --> 00:17.691
大海在咆哮

00:17.691 --> 00:50.279
鲸鱼在召唤
```

The only difference (apart from contents) I can tell between demo.captions.vtt and demo.captions_C.vtt is that the latter uses utf8 encoding, while the first one is using us-ascii.

I am wondering (a) if I have missed anything in the html code in integrating with the video tag in configuring tracks. Why only English is displayed. (b) has anyone successfully used vtt file that is using UTF-8 encoding? please let me know your procedures.

Comment: All valid WebVTT files use UTF-8 encoding. But the first 128 chars in UTF-8 are encoded the same as in ASCII for compatibility. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15965904/740233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example with Chinese subtitles: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xrpnbwfz/1/

```
<video id="dotsub_example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264"  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" controls preload="auto" data-setup='[]'>
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
<track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/chi_hans/vtt' srclang='zh' label='Chinese' default />
<track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/eng/vtt' srclang='en' label='English' />
<track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/spa/vtt' srclang='es' label='Spanish' />
<track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/fre_ca/vtt' srclang='fr' label='French' />
</video>
```

If you are using the latest version 4.12, there are some known issues with captions/subtitles: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1888 https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1904
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+caption

Comment: Excellent. It works! Yes, I am using the latest 4.12.